# How does a subdirectory knows about other subdirectories in CMAKE?

Tags: cmake

So example I have a project like this:

```
-CMakeList.txt
-lib/
--CMakeList.txt
-doctest/
--Some doctest files...
```

And in /CMakeList.txt I add subdirectory of doctest and my lib. So in lib/CMakeList.txt I can simply write in target_link_libraries doctest::doctest_with_main, how does it know about existing of doctest and how this namespaces works in CMake? Also I link that library with executable target myTests, and then in configuration it appears to be not in CMakeApplication, but in Doctest instead.

```
-CMake Application
--myMainApp
--doctest_with_main
--myLib
-Doctest
--myTests
```

[that pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqkvc.png)

Comment: Everything cmake does is contolled by the instructions in the make file. Maybe you can show the content of the two *CMakeList.txt* files.

Comment: CMake basically creates a database of all public/global targets and and variables, so they can be used by all CMakeLists.txt files.

Comment: Note that order matters for adding directories here.